# Python.Net - How to run python script from file(.Py)

Tags: c#, python.net

How to run .py files and call function by using python.Net library.
i have tried below code but it is not running.

```
    using (Py.GIL()){
      var fromFile = PythonEngine.Compile(null, @"C:\PycharmProjects\pythonenet\main.py", RunFlagType.File);
      fromFile.InvokeMethod("replace");//
    }
```

main.py file:

```
import re
def replace():
 print(re.sub(r"\s","*","Python is a programming langauge"))
```

When i try to run from string it is working.

```
       using (Py.GIL()){
          string co = @"def someMethod():
                print('This is from static script')";
          var fromString = PythonEngine.ModuleFromString("someName", co);
          fromString.InvokeMethod("someMethod");   
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i ended up with the following solution.

```
using (Py.GIL()){
    dynamic os = Py.Import("os");
    dynamic sys = Py.Import("sys");
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.expanduser(filePath)));
    var fromFile = Py.Import(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath));
    fromFile.InvokeMethod("replace");
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).